# convert a collections property to geojson object

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a lot of json objects in my collection "Rules", this is how they are structured.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c905dbab72577206000002"),
    "where" : {
        "Data" : "Custom",
        "OP" : "And",
        "Extra" : [ 
            {
                "radius" : "100",
                "place" : "fortis noida",
                "lat" : 28.618433,
                "lng" : 77.37358599999993
            }, 
            {
                "radius" : "300",
                "place" : "dilshad garden",
                "lat" : 28.6842763,
                "lng" : 77.3152116
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now as you can see I have a property, "Where" with a property "Extra" which is only populated if the "Where"->"Data" = "custom"

This property extra may contain a list of locations, with lat long of each location.

Now I have got a need, and I think my db is wrongly structured for this need, as I need an api on it which will get Point (Lat, Long) and Radius (in  as input param, and return only the Objects which are in the range of the given Lat,long.
Now I believe the right way would be to have my objects in form of a geojson object, but i think its too late for that, as I have a production running with this structure.

One more thing I would like to ask out of the line is - "is it possible to not return a complete object in a mongo query rather return the given properties of the objects only with object _id  of-course?".

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're correct that your data is in the wrong format for geo queries. The format either needs to be [legacy coordinate pairs or GeoJSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#location-data).

The method for returning only part of document from a query is called [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).